# How to Clear first tab view data in android Tab View

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I implemented `TabView` with `ViewPager` for my Application. The issue is that when I swipe view from the first tab to the second tab the view which related to first tab remaining same. I need to clear all `TextViews` once I leaving that view.

What I found that when I click the first tab it loads two `Fragments`
I solve that?

```
   private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new VoiceFragment(), "Voice");
        adapter.addFragment(new DataFragment(), "Data");
        adapter.addFragment(new IddFragment(), "Idd");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        switch (openedActivity) {
            case "Voice":
                pageId = 0;
                break;
            case "Data":
                pageId = 1;
                break;
            case "Idd":
                pageId = 2;
                break;
        }
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageId);
    }
```

Comment: use addOnPageChangeListener and clear data

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: I added setupViewPager method

Answer (score 0):

You need to set offscreenpage limit of your viewpager to 1.

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: checked.but not resolved.

Comment: I think that view not get refreshed once I move from the second tab to first. It keeps same view.

Comment: DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES is already 1 and Plus it cannot be changed as per than the  DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES